# What is the alternative for groups mode of frame clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am newly learning advanced SQL. As part of it I have come across window functions and frame clauses in the window functions. This article has a very good explanation of these topics and is based on PostgreSQL.

https://mjk.space/advances-sql-window-frames/

Now I am trying to write an query in SQL Server.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [transactions]
(
    [transaction_id] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [user_id] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [is_blocked] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [transaction_amount] [float] NULL,
    [transaction_category_id] [float] NULL
)
```

For this table I want to write a query such that for every transaction it returns the number of transactions done by that user in the previous 7 days –

My query

```
SELECT
    transaction_id, [user_id], [date],
    COUNT(transaction_id) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY [date] 
                                ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS transactions_count
FROM
    transactions
```

The problem of this query is the duplicate of dates. When there are duplicates the articles says we use `GROUPS` instead of `ROWS`. But I have realised from SQL Server docs that it supports only `ROWS` and `RANGE`. So how to handle this duplicates problem in SQL Server. What is the alternative for `GROUPS` in SQL Server ?

Comment: missed adding the article. added it

Comment: Can you provide a sample set of data and a desired output? It looks like, because you are including the transaction_id, you'll have a duplicate date for each user and each transaction ID. I believe you want to see a distinct date per user with a count of transactions for that user in the trailing 7 days of that date.

Comment: Considering that you're partitioning the window based on `[user_id]`. Even if there are orders placed on duplicate dates, they should be considered in the sum of transaction count for last 7 days.

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien for every transaction I would like to get the number of transactions done by that user in the previous 7 days

Answer (score 0):

The Windowed function here will look for the leading or lagging n rows, however because we do not know how many rows we may want to look at I don't believe a windowed function is the best way to do this. I would self join the table.

EDIT: I added a fill table to fill dates in the result set when the user did not perform any transactions. This returns a result for every user for every date between the earliest and latest date in the data set. If you don't need this, feel free to remove the @cal and @fill references.

First: here is the sample data set I'm working with. I created a calendar and fill table to report on days for when there were no transactions for a specific user.

```
DECLARE @transactions TABLE (
    [transaction_id] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [user_id] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [is_blocked] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [transaction_amount] [float] NULL,
    [transaction_category_id] [float] NULL
) 

INSERT INTO @transactions
VALUES
('1',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0),1,0,13,16),('2',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0),1,0,13,16),('3',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-1,1,0,13,16),('4',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-1,2,0,13,16),('5',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-1,1,0,13,16),('6',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-2,1,0,13,16),('7',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-3,1,0,13,16),('8',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-3,2,0,13,16),('9',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-3,2,0,13,16),('10',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-3,1,0,13,16),
('11',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-4,1,0,13,16),('12',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-4,1,0,13,16),('13',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-5,1,0,13,16),('14',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-5,2,0,13,16),('15',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-5,1,0,13,16),('16',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-6,1,0,13,16),('17',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-7,1,0,13,16),('18',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-7,2,0,13,16),('19',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-7,2,0,13,16),('20',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-8,1,0,13,16),
('21',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-9,1,0,13,16),('22',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-9,1,0,13,16),('23',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-10,1,0,13,16),('24',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-10,2,0,13,16),('25',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-10,1,0,13,16),('26',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-11,1,0,13,16),('27',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-12,1,0,13,16),('28',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-12,2,0,13,16),('29',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-12,2,0,13,16),('30',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-12,1,0,13,16)
,('21',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-34,1,0,13,16),('21',DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)-30,1,0,13,16)

--Create calendar table based on transactions table to ensure all dates are covered.
DECLARE @date DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM @transactions)
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM @transactions)
DECLARE @cal TABLE (
date DATETIME
)

WHILE @date <= @endDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @cal SELECT @date
    SET @date += 1
END

--Create filler table to account for missing transaction dates

DECLARE @fill TABLE (
    [user_id] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL
) 

INSERT INTO @fill
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.[user_id],
    b.[date]
FROM @transactions a
FULL JOIN @cal b ON 1 = 1
WHERE a.[date] <> b.date
```

And here is the query. This query does not include transactions on the day being reported, only the 7 previous days. This can be adjusted in the Join clause.

```
SELECT
    a.[user_id]
    ,a.[date]
    ,COUNT(b.transaction_id) AS Trailing7DayTransactionCount
FROM @transactions a
LEFT JOIN @transactions b ON
    b.[date] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-7,a.[date]) AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,a.[date])  --Look for transactions in the last 7 days. Because BETWEEN is inclusive, we look for -7 to -1.
    AND b.user_id = a.user_id   --Looking for historical transactions for the same user.
GROUP BY
    a.[user_id]
    ,a.[date]
ORDER BY 
    a.[user_id]
    ,a.[date] DESC
```

[Here is the SQL Fiddle for the output.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ad5d36/1)

Answer (score 0):

> For this table I want to write a query which returns the number of transactions for an user in the previous 7 days.

I would suggest `apply` for this:

My query

```
SELECT t.*, t2.transactions_count_prev7
FROM transactions t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as transactions_count_prev7
      FROM transactions t2
      WHERE t2.user_id = t.user_id AND
            t2.date <= t.date AND
            t2.date > DATEADD(day, -7, t.date)
     ) t2
```

Notes:

- The `GROUP` modifier not needed.  This syntax is supported by `RANGE` . . . but SQL Server doesn't fully support range.
- I am guessing that you want 7 days, including the current day.  So, this uses `>` rather than `>=`.
- The performance should be reasonable with an index on `transactions(user_id, date)`.

Comment: this is working fine and I want to order by results by user_id, date. what is the indexing that I can do for giving the best results for this query?

Comment: @cvg . . . The last bullet point in the question answers that question.